# Plants anti-aging process

Tags: botany

Every cell has its division limit. But plants cell looks like don't have it (like Sequoia sempervivens D.). I searched a little for it but what I have found didn't help to answer my question. I found a paper http://epsce.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/EMBRYONIC-PLANT-EXTRACTS-EXTEND-THE-HAYFLICK-LIMIT.pdf, which states that plants cell have something call EPE. Which seems to me like super telomerase ( Just kidding don't take it seriously).

My question is: How do plants slow their aging process? Have they different limits for cell division? Are phytohormones related to this phenomena?

Comment: I am not so big plant fan. So sorry if is just basic questions for you guys.

Comment: Can anybody even tried to answer this. I am really curious about aging process in plants. Any articles about it might help too.

Comment: Sequoias are perhaps not the best example.  Consider clonal organisms like the quaking aspen (Populus tremuloides), one grove of which is estimated to be about 80,000 years old (and some suggest much older): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pando_(tree)

Comment: Wow didnt know about it. And now the question about aging is much more interesting!!

Comment: Check this paper, it is a great starting point! https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1568163713000615?via%3Dihub